# Display SOLDOUT text in Dropdowns of Variable Product in WooCommerce

Tags: ajax, woocommerce-offtopic

I have 2 variants of a variable product in WooCommerce:

1. colour [Red]
2. size [2, 4]

**Stock Status:**

- Red + 2 = instock
- Red + 4 = **outofstock**

When I select 'Red', I want to display **'SOLD OUT'** text after **'4'** in SIZE DROPDOWN dropdown (i.e. **4 - SOLD OUT**).

This may require: **AJAX**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Step 1: Add below code to **variable.php** file located in woocommerce plugin (single-product/add-to-cart)

```
<?php
    $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    echo '<ul class="attr_avail_custom dnone">';
    foreach ($product_variations as $variation)  {
        $var_data = $variation['attributes'];

        if(!$variation['is_in_stock']) {
            echo '<li>';
            foreach ($var_data as $vk => $vv) {

                echo "<span data-key=$vk data-value=$vv >$vv</span>";
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }

    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

#### Step 2: Add below code to your javascript file

```
    //SOLD OUT text jquery for Prdocut detailed pages...
    if( jQuery('ul.attr_avail_custom').length > 0 ) { /*loading jQuery only if the current page is product's detail page*/

        //On hovering mouse over the SIZE dropdown - adding SOLD OUT text according to the hidden 'out of stock' attributes available in 'ul.attr_avail_custom'...
        jQuery('select[id*="size"]').hover(function () {
            var selected_color = jQuery('select[id*="colour"]').val();

            //firslty removing SOLD OUT from all if added previously...
            jQuery('select[id*="size"] option:not([value=""])').each(function () {
                jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).val());
            });

            /*checking if the selected colour is in the SOLD OUT pair printed (above select boxes) in hidden and coded in this file woocommerce (single-product\add-to-cart\variable.php) */
            jQuery('ul.attr_avail_custom [data-key*="colour"][data-value="' + selected_color + '"]').each(function () { /*out of stock size loop fro selected colour*/
                var out_stock_colour_val = jQuery(this).data('value');
                var out_stock_size_val = jQuery(this).parent().find('[data-key*="size"]').data('value');

                //Finally adding SOLD OUT text...
                jQuery('select[id*="size"] option[value="' + out_stock_size_val + '"]').text(out_stock_size_val + ' - SOLD OUT');

            });
        });

        //if mouse is hover over COLOUR dropdown - we must have to (1) Flush the SIZE if seleceted and (2) Triggering clicks on both Dropdowns to prevent AJAX conflicts... (this is required)
        jQuery('select[id*="colour"]').hover(function () {
            //Flushing selecrted SIZE and triggering click..
            jQuery('select[id*="size"]').trigger('click');

            jQuery('select[id*="size"] option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');

            //triggering click on COLOUR dropdown..
            jQuery('select[id*="colour"]').trigger('click');

        });
    }
```

**Note:** Remember to overwrite your **variable.php** file in your theme folder. [Click here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) to learn how to do that.